How to insert a dynamic component inside a element in Angular
Imagine we have a html structure as follows
<div [innerHTML]="contentFromAPI | safeHTML"></div>

Now the content from the api would be a string consists of more HTML elements. Making the structure something like this:
<div>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
</div>

I want to create a component dynamically and insert it at the middle of the child nodes. In this case at the 5th place.
For this I'm doing something like this:
html file:
<div [innerHTML]="contentFromAPI | safeHTML" #articleContent></div>

ts file:
@ViewChild('articleContent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  private articleContent!: ViewContainerRef;

ngOnChanges(){
 if(ads){
   this.addElementToTemplate();
 }
}

private addElementToTemplate() {
setTimeout(() => {
      const childrenLength =
        this.articleContent.element.nativeElement.children.length;
        this.articleContent.createComponent(DynamicElement,{index: Math.ceil(childrenLength/2)});
    }, 3000);
}

but this adds the component as a sibling to content element. Something like this:
<div>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
</div>
<dynamic-element></dynamic-element>


Stuff rendered inside innerHTML will not have angular functionality working! you can just split the innerHTML into two contents and render them above and below your dynamic component!

It is possible to insert an Angular component inside innerHTML but we should note that elements inserted this way are outside Angular context and change detection will not work, so it will behave like a normal HTML element. It's better you look for alternative approaches and not using innerHTML.
Please find below example highlighting my point that change detection does not work inside innerHTML.
Full code
import {
  ApplicationRef,
  Component,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  createComponent,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { SafeHtmlPipe } from './safe-html.pipe';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DynamicComponent } from './app/dynamic/dynamic.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SafeHtmlPipe, CommonModule, DynamicComponent],
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="contentFromAPI | safeHtml" #articleContent></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('articleContent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  private articleContent!: ViewContainerRef;
  name = 'Angular';
  contentFromAPI = `
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5. insert here!</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  `;

  constructor(
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addElementToTemplate();
  }

  private addElementToTemplate() {
    const environmentInjector = this.applicationRef.injector;
    const componentRef = createComponent(DynamicComponent, {
      environmentInjector,
    });
    const insertElement = this.articleContent.element.nativeElement;
    console.log(insertElement);
    this.renderer2.appendChild(
      insertElement.children[4],
      componentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    this.articleContent.createComponent(DynamicComponent, {
      index: 0,
    });
    componentRef.hostView.detectChanges();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

thanks for the solution @NarenMurali , for my use case this solution fits perfectly, as the dynamic component I'm rendering has a static content, with some event emitters, which works perfectly fine.

From what I understand from the question, here is a solution which can be worked out in the .ts file.
this.contentFromAPI = //your data from API here;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(this.contentFromAPI, 'text/html');

// Get the element at the 5th position
//add logic to find middle node here instead of 4
const targetElement = doc.body.childNodes[4];

const componentElement = document.createElement('your-dynamic-component');


targetElement.parentNode.insertBefore(componentElement, targetElement);

// Update the contentFromAPI with the modified HTML structure
this.contentFromAPI = doc.body.innerHTML;

hope this would helps :)

not sure if this will work for angular component selectors since, it has to be created dynamically and just using document.createElement won't work I think.
